# how to find multi setter with Spring Boot BeanWrapper

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, kotlin

I hava a class Packet.java(can't modify) in a package.

```
public class Packet implements java.io.Serializable, Cloneable {

   private static final AtomicLong ID_ATOMICLONG = new AtomicLong();

   private Long id = ID_ATOMICLONG.incrementAndGet();
}
```

I use own class LoginPacket.kt (can modify)

```
class LoginPacket : Packet () {
   var id = "" ( this name must be id )
   fun parsePacket(input: String): Boolean {
    val map = HashMap<String,Any>()
    map["id"] = "5d6ff3433354b4d43076419"
    var wrapper: BeanWrapper = PropertyAccessorFactory.forBeanPropertyAccess(this)
    wrapper.isAutoGrowNestedPaths = true
    // question is here , I can not set id as String use BeanWrapper, Only can set id as Long
    // and also I can replace id's getter and setter method
    val pd = wrapper.getPropertyDescriptor("id")
    pd.readMethod = LoginPacket::id.getter.javaMethod
    pd.writeMethod = LoginPacket::id.setter.javaMethod
    wrapper.setPropertyValues(map)
   }
}
```

So what I can do next?

Thanks very much for sharing!

[Beanwrapper link](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/BeanWrapper.html)

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to override the type of a field.

What you can do instead depends on what you are trying to do, and which libraries you are using.

I can think of one way that may work, assuming your library does not need an instance nor subclass of `Packet`.
And that is creating your own class that only implements the interfaces:

```
class LoginPacket(): java.io.Serializable, Cloneable {

   // You may or may not need this.
   // Since the original version uses it to generate the ID, 
   // I think you can skip this part.
   companion object {
       @JvmStatic
       private val ID_ATOMICLONG = AtomicLong()   
   }

   var id : String = ""

   fun parsePacket(input: String): Boolean {
       val map = HashMap<String,Any>()
       map["id"] = "5d6ff3433354b4d43076419"
       var wrapper: BeanWrapper = PropertyAccessorFactory.forBeanPropertyAccess(this)
       wrapper.isAutoGrowNestedPaths = true
       val pd = wrapper.getPropertyDescriptor("id")
       pd.readMethod = LoginPacket::id.getter.javaMethod
       pd.writeMethod = LoginPacket::id.setter.javaMethod
       wrapper.setPropertyValues(map)
   }
}
```

It is hard to provide better answers without more context.